# logstash remove_field not working in order to upload csv to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I'm using elasticsearch, kibana and logstash 6.0.1.

I wish to upload csv data to elasticsearch by logstash and removing fields (path, @timestamp, @version, host and message). I'm showing logstash.conf and emp.csv files below. The upload will work if I don't use the remove_field instruction but I need to. Furthermore, the index was not created.

logstash.conf:

```
input {

  file {
      path => "e:\emp.csv"
      start_position => "beginning"
  }
}
filter {
  csv {
      separator => ","
      columns => ["code","color"]
      remove_field => ["path", "@timestamp", "@version", "host", "message"]
  }

  mutate {convert => ["code", "string"]}
  mutate {convert => ["color", "string"]}

}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "http://localhost:9200"
    index => "emp5"
    user => "elastic"
    password => "password"
  }
  stdout {}
}
```

emp.csv:

```
1,blue
2,red
```

What is missing in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `csv` file the data is not available that you are trying to delete.

Instead try this to delete for example `path` and `host` field:

```
(...)
filter {
  csv {
      separator => ","
      columns => ["code","color"]
  }
    mutate {
      remove_field => ["path", "host"]
    }
(...)
```

And for information, if field `path` and/or `host` doesn't exist, there's no problem. The plugin will remove field if field exists, and just do nothing if field does not exist.

**Edit**:
I have tested it on fresh `elastic stack`:

You can delete index with:

```
curl -X DELETE "localhost:9200/emp5"
```

Also note that in your current config `logstash` will read the file only once.
You can change that behaviour by adding `sincedb_path => "/dev/null"`
or in `Windows` case: `sincedb_path => "NUL"` inside:

```
input {
    file {
           (...) # here
         }
```

section.

Then after `logstash` work verify result with:

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/emp5?pretty"
{
  "emp5" : {
    "aliases" : { },
    "mappings" : {
      "doc" : {
        "properties" : {
          "@timestamp" : {
            "type" : "date"
          },
          "@version" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "code" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "color" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "message" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "number_of_shards" : "5",
        "blocks" : {
          "read_only_allow_delete" : "true"
        },
        "provided_name" : "emp5",
        "creation_date" : "1576099826712",
        "number_of_replicas" : "1",
        "uuid" : "reXYzqPgQryYcASoov9l5A",
        "version" : {
          "created" : "6080599"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see there is no `host` and `path` field.

Comment: Ok. I added remove_field to mutate but I got same results. The index is not created.

Comment: @user3637971 you say you added it, but did you also remove it from `csv` filter?

Comment: I added to mutate and I removed from csv filter.

Comment: @user3637971 I edited the answer to help you further.

Comment: Yes, you're right. It's working removing path and host. Then I added message, timestamp and version to remove_field. Adding sincedb_path => "NUL" was necessary. Thanks.